# Match with OR clause after Unwind in MongoDB aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have a MongoDB aggregate query like this

```
[{ "$match" : { "isDeleted" : false } }
, { "$match" : { "$or" : [{ "arrayCol.col_1" : "Yes", "arrayCol.subArrCol.col_2" : 10 }, { "arrayCol.subArrCol.col_3" : 2000 }] } }
, { "$project" : { "_id" : 0, "col_0" : "$col_0", "col_1" : "$arrayCol.col_1", "col_2" : "$arrayCol.subArrCol.col_2", "col_3" : "$arrayCol.subArrCol.col_3" } }]
```

which is currently returning 2 documents like below

```
/* 1 */
{
    "col_0" : "xyz",
    "col_1" : "Yes",
    "col_2" : [
        10
    ],
    "col_3" : [
        2013,
        1995
    ]
},

/* 2 */
{
    "col_0" : "pqr",
    "col_1" : "Yes",
    "col_2" : [
        9,
        10
    ],
    "col_3" : [
        2000,
        2000
    ]
}
```

Now I want to unwind both "col_2" and "col_3", but it should return only those docs like before, ie those docs with either col_2 = 10 or col_3 = 2000.

My expected result set is like follows,

```
/* 1 */
{
    "col_0" : "xyz",
    "col_1" : "Yes",
    "col_2" : 10,
    "col_3" : 2013
},

/* 2 */
{
    "col_0" : "pqr",
    "col_1" : "Yes",
    "col_2" : 9,
    "col_3" : 2000
}
/* 3 */
{
    "col_0" : "pqr",
    "col_1" : "Yes",
    "col_2" : 10,
    "col_3" : 2000
}
```

If the match condition was an AND clause, then I could have added the same match condition once again after the unwinds to eliminate the wrong values.
But how can I solve this in OR clause/ Can anyone please help?
I am new to MongoDB.

Documents in my collection are as follows,

```
{
    "_id": "1234-5f33-4703-be7f-3ea679951af3",
    "col_0": "xyz",
    "arrayCol": {
        "col_1": "Yes",
        "subArrCol": [
            {
                "col_2": 10,
                "col_3": 2013
            },
            {
                "col_3": 1995
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5678-5f33-4703-be7f-3ea679951af3",
    "col_0": "pqr",
    "arrayCol": {
        "col_1": "Yes",
        "subArrCol": [
            {
                "col_2": 9,
                "col_3": 2000
            },
            {
                "col_2": 10,
                "col_3": 2000,
                "col_4": "abc"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Both collection and expected result set are added. Also the query changed a bit for better clarity. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$unwind` deconstruct `col_3` and `col_2` arrays
- `$match` your conditions
- `$group` by root to remove duplicate documents
- `$replaceWith` to replace _id object to root document

```
  { $match: { ... } }, //skipped 
  { $project: { ... } }, //skipped 

  { $unwind: "$col_3" },
  { $unwind: "$col_2" },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          col_1: "Yes",
          col_2: 10
        },
        { col_3: 2000 }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $group: { _id: "$$ROOT" } },
  { $replaceWith: "$_id" }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rBNZPlgj7AU)